# How do I create separate mailbox configurations per virtual user with Dovecot?

Tags: email, dovecot, imap

Let's say I have two virtual users: `bugs@domain.tld` and `admin@domain.tld`.

I want the mailboxes for `bugs` to be configured like this...:

```
mailbox Sent {
  special_use = \Sent
}
mailbox Drafts {
  special_use = \Drafts
}
mailbox "Priority 1" {
  auto = subscribe
}
mailbox "Priority 2" {
  auto = subscribe
}
mailbox "Priority 3" {
  auto = subscribe
}
mailbox Unreplied {
  auto = subscribe
}
mailbox Resolved {
  auto = subscribe
}
```

...but have the mailboxes for `admin` have some different folders configured:

```
mailbox Sent {
  special_use = \Sent
}
mailbox Drafts {
  special_use = \Drafts
}
mailbox System {
  auto = subscribe
}
mailbox DMARC {
  auto = subscribe
}
mailbox Archives {
  auto = create
  special_use = \Archive
}
mailbox Trash {
  special_use = \Trash
}
mailbox Spam {
  auto = create
  special_use = \Junk
}
```

I **don't** want the folders for the `bugs` email to be copied over to the `admin` email, and vice versa.

What I've tried is using namespaces and then setting each virtual user's inbox namespace name via my passwd file, like this:

```
admin:<password>::::::userdb_mail=maildir:/home/mail/admin NAMESPACE=primary userdb_namespace/primary/inbox=yes userdb_namespace/primary/list=yes userdb_namespace/primary/prefix=primary/

bugs:<password>::::::userdb_mail=maildir:/home/mail/bugs NAMESPACE=bugs userdb_namespace/bugs/inbox=yes userdb_namespace/bugs/list=yes userdb_namespace/bugs/prefix=bugs/
```

but Dovecot's logs say:

`namespace configuration error: Duplicate namespace prefix: "" in=0 out=408 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0`

My full `15-mailboxes.conf`:

```
namespace bugs {
  list = no
  type = private
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox "Priority 1" {
    auto = subscribe
  }
  mailbox "Priority 2" {
    auto = subscribe
  }
  mailbox "Priority 3" {
    auto = subscribe
  }
  mailbox Unreplied {
    auto = subscribe
  }
  mailbox Resolved {
    auto = subscribe
  }
}
namespace primary {
  list = no
  type = private
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox System {
    auto = subscribe
  }
  mailbox DMARC {
    auto = subscribe
  }
  mailbox Archives {
    auto = create
    special_use = \Archive
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  mailbox Spam {
    auto = create
    special_use = \Junk
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disable & move duplicate prefixes out of the way, then revert these changes from `userdb`.**

While you cannot have two namespaces defined with the same prefix - you do not have to *define* them that way if you are *overriding* via `userdb` anyway.

```
# in global configuration
namespace primary {
  disabled = yes
  prefix = /disable-namespace
  ...
}

# in userdb: newlines for readability
userdb_mail=maildir:/home/mail/admin
userdb_namespace=primary
userdb_namespace/primary/disabled=no
userdb_namespace/primary/prefix=
userdb_namespace/primary/inbox=yes
```

Careful with `list=no`, it does not prevent access. It merely removes the folders from the `LIST` output, the folder is still there (and thus precludes a second one with matching prefix!)

> It is still possible to list the namespace’s folders by explicitly
> asking for them.

Note: That `NAMESPACE=primary` in your question looks out of place, why is that in the userdb (but not prefixed userdb_)?